# How to hide or remove Developer Story tab

Tags: discussion, support, developer-story

I need to hide or remove the Developer Story tab. How can I do that?

Comment: Wait for it! :)

Comment: ok @ManojKumar...

Comment: Why do you want to hide it for yourself? What is the possible benefit there?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the privacy settings to 'private', i.e. untick the *Show the developer story tab* checkbox, then the tab is only visible to you.

You probably already did that, since I don't see a developer story tab in your profile.

Comment: I did that, I made it private, if I dont want to show in my profile itself

Comment: Install stylish and add the rule `a.story-tab { display:none; }`

Comment: @rene, its worked

Answer (score -2):

Install a plugin called Stylish and do the follow the screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]