# How to remove the sticky nav bar at the top in the redesigned SO using stylish?

Tags: support, design, top-bar

I'm trying to get rid of the new sticky nav bar using stylish but I haven't been successful so far. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Unlike [Unstick new navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar) this is not a feature request. I'm asking how to change the sticky behavior on the client side, in my browser.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not a duplicate. See edit.

Comment: What you're asking seems to be outside of the scope of Meta.

Comment: @vaultah where is it supposed to go then?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/?

Comment: @vaultah Not clear why. It's a question about using SO, along the lines of [How to hide or remove Developer Story tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336360) and  [How to hide pending review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327378)

Comment: @zaq Note that neither of those ask specifically for a Stylish rule. They just ask "how can I". I see it as similar to the difference between "What's a good plugin to foo the bar?" and "How can I foo the bar?".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The mention of Stylish was not there originally; it was added as a way to explain why this is not a duplicate of [Unstick new navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341885). The same could be explained differently, so I edited the post.

Comment: @zaq: fwiw, the mention of Stylish has been there from [the very beginning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/342146/1).

Comment: @TravisJ already have tried that with several elements of the header and the header itself. No luck..

Comment: @TravisJ the snark wasn't necessary. Like I said earlier that actually was one of the first things I tried and it didn't work. Maybe they updated the layout in a way that makes it easy to change that behavior via css now. I can't see the top bar now so I can't test this again.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question about stylish, but [we're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation).

Comment: @KurtisBeavers that's even better! Thanks for listening to the feedback. I hope that you don't get rid of the option eventually but if you do, I hope that the css is straightforward enough that I can disable it with stylish. According to Travis that seems to be the case now so good job (I'm still unable to test it).

Comment: @TravisJ I hadn't checked. I enabled it now in order to test your answer.